# Are there ever more than one possible functor instance of a given type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

I have the feeling that, for any ADT, there is only ever one possible Functor instance.

Because the function `(a -> b)` for `fmap` only ever has one type to work with, and it always change all appearances of `a`, as it transforms `F a` to `F b`.

Is this statement true?

Comment: Functors aren't aloud to make any structural changes (according to the law `fmap id = id`). So yes, you're right.